# OracleType (.NET) Mappings in Oracle

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, oracle11g

I need to know the mappings aka Oracle equivalents of the .NET enum `System.Data.OracleClient.OracleType`. I know a lot of them are self explanatory but some are not, such as `OracleType.Int32` and `OracleType.Int16`. Do those refer to an int datatype? Since there is no int32 or int16 in Oracle. If someone could provide the mappings that would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using ODP.NET, here is the link to the documentation:

**ODP.NET Types Overview**
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/win.121/e17732/featTypes.htm#ODPNT281

(I'm not sure whether this is valid for both, ODP.NET Native Driver and ODP.NET Managed Driver)